# I need to change data type from float to decimal of a database currently got 1 billion records

Tags: mysql

I need to change data type from float to decimal of a database currently got 1 billion records. Is there any unforeseen issues? Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, Rumsfeldian systems administration. Known unknowns, unknown unknowns...

Comment: Make sure you test this in another environment before executing this in production!

Comment: Innodb? Myisam? Is the existing FLOAT column defined to allow NULLs? What is the exact numerical situation driving this requirement for conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is going to take a long time and take a lot of careful planning. You should plan for multiple days if you do it very carefully. If you just do an ALTER TABLE it might run for a week and then crash. I'm not kidding.

Can you avoid doing this? Can you create a view that shows the float column as decimal? You would be smart to try to avoid it.

If you must go forward with this, you should try adding a new column to the table rather than altering the existing one.  Suppose your old column is called `metric` and the new one is called `dmetric`. Further suppose that your `metric` column is defined NOT NULL.

Then create the new column so it does allow NULLs.

Then put an index on the new column.

Then run this UPDATE query a half million times or so, until it processes no rows.

```
UPDATE table SET dmetric = metric
 WHERE dmetric IS NULL
 LIMIT 2000
```

That will do the conversion in reasonably sized chunks, and keep transactions (if you're in the innodb world) from getting too large.

Do try this on a copy of the table.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, how about embrace float to float(10,3), do you know any breaks will happen? Thanks Phuong

Comment: `FLOAT(10,3)` is the same thing as `DOUBLE`. You'll have similar problems converting a column from `FLOAT` to that format as you would converting it to `DECIMAL(10,3)`.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, the reason we need to change to data type because it was float so it's only 6 digits by default, so the value used to be below 999.999. Now it counts up to 1000.01 for such (because of 6 digits it truncate the precision down to 2 digits) , my employer wants 3 digits precision all the time for the accuracy of the data...then the legacy data type Float will surely prone to the accuracy problem in the future. We got 56 columns Float need to change to Decimal, I dont know how am I going do that safely...

Comment: What sort of data is it? If it's money amounts, decimal is appropriate. If it's physical measurements, float or double is probably appropriate. As you know, the accuracy of physical measurements depends on the instrumentation. For example, if you're dealing with commercial-grade GPS, using more than FLOAT (32-bit) precision is an exercise in self-delusion: GPS isn't that good. If it's data from the Large Hadron Collider, you definitely want DOUBLE. Either way, my answer suggests a valid conversion strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to to this, which will work if your giga-row table has ID numbers or some other workable primary key. This will allow you to upgrade your precision without much downtime.

Create a new table -- call it `precision_value` -- with two columns:

```
id       BIGINT NOT NULL pk
dmetric  DOUBLE (or DECIMAL(10,3))
```

Change your queries that need higher precision to something like this.

```
SELECT a.id, ..., 
       COALESCE(b.dmetric, a.metric) dmetric,
       ...
  FROM your_big_table a
  LEFT JOIN `precision_value` b ON a.id = b.id
```

This use of `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` will look for each value first in your new table, then in your existing table. If the higher-precision value is present, you'll get it back from the new table, otherwise you'll get the original value.  It might be convenient to create a view for this.

Then, insert your newly arriving high precision data values, new observations, etc, into your new table as well as your existing one

```
 INSERT INTO your_big_table (metric, whatever) VALUES ('1.234567890', 'whatever');
 INSERT INTO precision_values (id, dmetric) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1.234567890')
```

This new table is basically a lookaside table for higher-precision data.

Finally, round your output appropriately to your application. For example, if you want three decimal places, this will do it.

```
SELECT a.id, ..., 
       ROUND(COALESCE(b.dmetric, a.metric),3) dmetric,
```